# Debugger não funciona

Tags: javascript, c#

Tenho a seguinte função em `C#` e em `JAVASCRIPT` quando eu coloco um ponto de parada (F9) na função em `c#` ele funciona normalmente, mas o `debugger` não, ele não para, estou fazendo algo errado?

Estou usando Visual Studio 2017

```
 @functions{

        public string obterDado2()
        {
            string Validador = TipoPecaController.validar2;
            return Validador;
        }
        public string alterar()
        {
            TipoPecaController.validar2 = "";
            return TipoPecaController.validar2;
        }
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var vd = "";

        window.onload = function() {
            debugger;
            vd = @obterDado2();
            debugger;
            if (vd == "True") {

                alertify.alert("Aviso", "Esse Tipo de Peça já existe, tente cadastrar um diferente", function () {
                    alertify.message('OK');
                });
                vd = @alterar();
            }
            else if (vd == "Trues") {
                    alertify.alert("Aviso", "Essa sigla já existe, tente cadastrar uma sigla diferente", function () {
                        alertify.message('OK');
                    });
                    vd = @alterar();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: você tá dando `F12` no navegador?

Comment: Bom, eu sou iniciante e não sabia que era necessário o f12, vou testar, obrigado

Comment: isso é pra se quiser debugar sem a ide.. não sei se é seu caso

Comment: Gostaria que fosse pela ide, mas obrigado, vou buscar aprender sobre debugar pelo navegador

Comment: De que tipo de projeto do VS está falando?

Comment: Não sei entendi a pergunta exatamente, mas trabalho com asp.net

Comment: Me parece Razor Pages, a pergunta é se você está falando de MVC, Razor Pages, Web Forms, Blazor ou outra estrutura.

Comment: Bom, não sei se vou responder essa pergunta corretamente, como disse sou iniciante, mas deve ser Web Forms, pois estou trabalhando com formulários, não estou mais na empresa, mas vou postar o código todo amanha quando chegar lá

Comment: Se você quer debugar o javascript pelo VS 2017 você tem que utilizar/navegar aquela página que ele abre automaticamente quando você  aperta F5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exsitem alguns pontos a serem observados aqui, você está declarando as suas strings no javascript sem usar as aspas...

O resultado de `vd = @obterDado2();` seria `vd = True;` e não `vd = "True";`, veja a correção.

```
@functions{

    public static class TipoPecaController
    {
        public static string validar2 { get; set; } = "True";
    }

    public string obterDado2()
    {
        string Validador = TipoPecaController.validar2;
        return Validador;
    }
    public string alterar()
    {
        TipoPecaController.validar2 = "";
        return TipoPecaController.validar2;
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
        var vd = "";

        window.onload = function() {

            vd = "@obterDado2()";

            if (vd == "True") {

                alertify.alert("Aviso", "Esse Tipo de Peça já existe, tente cadastrar um diferente", function () {
                    alertify.message('OK');
                });
                vd = "@alterar()";
            }
            else if (vd == "Trues") {
                    alertify.alert("Aviso", "Essa sigla já existe, tente cadastrar uma sigla diferente", function () {
                        alertify.message('OK');
                    });
                    vd = "@alterar()";
            }
        }
</script>
```

Depois... a declaração `debugger`, serve apenas para o browser. O Visual Studio não irá pausar a execução nesse ponto. Para realizar o debug pela IDE basta posicionar um breakpoint onde deseja parar...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

... Porém você precisa se certificar que a funcionalidade de debuggar JS está habilitada em `Tools -> Options -> Debugging`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você consegue colocar um breakpoint em um if? Eu só consigo colocar onde tem um código c#

Comment: @JeffHenrique você conferiu as configurações do debugging? Está rorando o VS em modo Administrador? Corrigiu os erros que eu apontei no javascript?

Comment: Corrigi os erros, e verifiquei as configurações, porém não executei em modo administrador, vou tentar

Comment: Executando como administrador deu certo, obrigado Leandro